# Routable Url in asp.net with .HTML gives 404 error in hosted server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Routable url for my site http://www.indiatimepass.info it works fine in url is without any "." (dot) but if i add a "." (dot) in url it gives me no page found error.

http://www.indiatimepass.info/link/11/welcome.html gives error

http://www.indiatimepass.info/tags/asp.net also give error

http://www.indiatimepass.info/tags/free bse tips works fine

Thanks in advance.

Comment: UrlScan module has a feature to forbid dots in path. Is it installed on your server?

Comment: @ArtemKoshelev i don't think so but it not give any error for this link also http://www.indiatimepass.info/register.aspx which is allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer...

```
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>
            <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, system.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
```

Thanks.